# Quando foi que a palavra "transar" passou a significar "ter relações sexuais" em pt-BR?

Tags: significado, história

Transar é definido no [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/transar) como:

- verbo transitivo

  1. [Brasil, Informal]  Ajustar um acordo ou um negócio.
- verbo transitivo e intransitivo

  2. [Brasil, Informal]  Ter relações sexuais.

Suponho, portanto, que o verbo não seja usado em pt-PT em nenhuma das duas acepções.  Quando foi que "transar" passou a ter também o significado de "ter relações sexuais", neste lado de cá do Atlântico?  Descrito como "informal" pelo Priberam, não teria sido considerado gíria durante muito tempo?

Comment: É, "transar" só é usado em Portugal como brasileirismo.

Comment: Interessante que “transação” não tem esse contexto.

Comment: Também não consigo precisar, mas se serve de alguma referência, na novela O Bem Amado (1973) os personagens jovens usam frequentemente a expressão "transar legal" como referência a intimidade de um casal ("a gente tá transando legal" ou "você não quer transar legal?"), mas neste ponto ainda não parece ter a conotação explícita de sexo.

Comment: Transação negocial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em Portugal a palavra é conhecida, mas não usada. No Brasil, o sentido ’relacionar-se sexualmente’ parece ter-se divulgado, se não mesmo aparecido, nos anos 70 do século passado. O primeiro exemplo que encontrei em que o sentido é quase de certeza esse é de 1976:

> Luciana — Que **transa** é essa, Marcinha?
> Márcia — Não estou falando de cama. Emocionalmente.
> [Revista de teatro nº 409-414, Sociedade Brasileira de Autores Teatrais, 1976](https://books.google.pt/books?id=rSpZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Que%20transa%20%C3%A9%20essa,%20Marcinha%22&dq=%22Que%20transa%20%C3%A9%20essa,%20Marcinha%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYvfKqqPD0AhU08uAKHSGXA64Q6AF6BAgCEAI)

Verdadeiramente explícito, só em 1980:

> Rapidamente, em uma só e mesma noite, podem partir para trocas de carícias, abraços, beijos e mesmo “**transar**”,⁹ e depois nem mais se encontrarem ou, se isto ocorrer, estabelecer uma amizade e se comportarem como se nada
> […]
> 9. **Transar**: Termo usado para “relacionar-se sexualmente”.
> [*Caderno do CEDES*, 1980](https://books.google.pt/books?id=PSwiAQAAIAAJ&q=transar&dq=transar&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwist7Cu-cLtAhU7AWMBHWicCtU4UBDoATAKegQIDRAC)

Naturalmente, a palavra já teria esse sentido antes na linguagem falada. Mas aparentemente esse sentido, se já existia, não era do conhecimento geral no início da década. Algumas publicações da altura comentam os novos usos de *transar* entre os jovens, mas não falam de ’relacionar-se sexualmente’:

> **O jargão da juventude**
> Para entender a garotada, os adultos de hoje devem renovar diàriamente o seu vocabulário. Pois todo dia há uma nova palavra em circulação entre os jovens. Por exemplo, diz Mônica: “Estou numa **transa** com o Marcelinho.” **Transar** (vem de **transação**) quer dizer combinar um encontro.
> [*Manchete*, Rio de Janeiro,  27-3-1971](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=004120&pesq=transar&pasta=ano%20197&pagfis=113397)
>
> **TRANSAR** - várias acepções. Aproveitar: Vamos **transar** uma praia? neste sentido substitui curtir; conspiração, segredo: a **transa** de Roberto Carlos e sua mulher; últimas, dicas, fofocas: quais são as **transas**?
> [*Letras de Hoje*, nº 15-18, 1974](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1_YvAAAAYAAJ&q=transar&dq=transar&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJwLa9-8LtAhWM2hQKHZceAtU4ZBDoATAOegQIDhAC)

Esta entrevista n’ [*O Pasquim* de 1972)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=004120&pesq=%22devem%20transar%20direito%22&pasta=ano%20197&pagfis=116300) é também reveladora: a entrevistada diz que prefere relacionar-se com mulheres, porque as mulheres “transam, ficam amigas”, enquanto homem “só quer é ( * ) a gente”, não está “a fim de transar comigo”. Não me parece que ela se exprimisse assim se soubesse que *transar* já era usado com o sentido de, usando a notação do jornal, ’( * )’.

Agora, recuando mais no tempo, há uma coisa interessante. O dicionário Houaiss diz que *transar* está atestado em 1365. Mas eu não encontro a palavra em português antes de 1899. O seu uso deve ter-se perdido. Encontro, com os significados ’transacionar’ e ’negociar’, é em castelhano, nomeadamente em publicações oriundas da Argentina e Uruguai. Foi possivelmente daí que a palavra foi recuperada. Coerente com isto, até 1960 encontro *transar* apenas em jornais do Paraná (mas não de Santa Catarina ou Rio Grande do Sul). Inicialmente, o sentido é ’transacionar’, como “transar apolices estadoaes e municipaes” ([Diario da Tarde, Curitiba, 1899](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=800074&pesq=%22transar%22&pasta=ano%20189&hf=memoria.bn.br&pagfis=551)); depois também acerca de acordos político-partidários, “transar apoio ao PTB” ([*Diário da Tarde*, Curitiba, 1960](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=800074&pesq=transar&pasta=ano%20196&pagfis=95669)).

Comment: very good job...

Answer (score 1):

> Suponho, portanto, que o verbo não seja usado em pt-PT (...)

Sem ser uma resposta directa ao essencial da pergunta, vale a pena acrescentar como resposta que o verbo *"transar"* chegou a Portugal com a primeira fase de emigração de cidadãos brasileiros que começou por volta do ano 2000 (no contexto da *"globalização"* que então se iniciava).

A definição do priberam não é inteiramente clara porque hoje em Portugal a maioria das pessoas conhecem a palavra mas não é usada com frequência.

Em termos de semântica faz contraste com os restantes vocábulos disponíveis por dar uma conotação menos carregada ao acto. Acepção que é talvez difícil de captar e descrever num dicionário.

> Descrito como "informal" pelo Priberam, não teria sido considerado gíria durante muito tempo?

Aqui é interessante fazer uma análise morfológica sobre as condições de sucesso do vocábulo, mais talvez do que uma análise sincrónica ou etimologica. (Situando o vocábulo não no tempo mas: No campo linguístico.)

*"Trans-ar"* vem do latim *"trans-actio"*. Há toda uma família de palavras que resultam da derivação da raiz *"trans"*. Mas ainda mais notável é o facto de *"trans"* ser não só uma raiz mas também um prefixo produtivo que pode aparecer em palavras que não estão sequer lexicalizadas sem por isso perder clareza de sentido. (É um dos prefixos mais compridos da língua portuguesa, tendo 5 letras.)

Acho que o verbo *"trans-ar"* teve o seu sucesso em termos linguísticos por ser a **verbalização** (no sentido gramátical de criar um verbo) de uma raiz muito comum.

Answer (score 1):

Transar e transação são palavras distintas.

Em seu primeiro exemplo - Ajustar um acordo ou um negócio.
verbo transitivo e intransitivo - a palavra correta a utilizar é transação. Seria um sinônimo de acordo. Também há transações financeira - "farei uma transação pelo banco pra você" significa que você fará alguma ação bancária, seja pagamentos, depósitos e outros. Jamais você usará a palavra TRANSAR aqui.

Pode até ser que a palavra TRANSAR tenha sido oriunda de TRANSAÇÃO, pois também se trata de um acordo (?). Mas realmente você utiliza essa palavra, no Brasil, apenas para relações sexuais.

Não tenho data alguma, mas creio que "ter relações sexuais" veio antes de TRANSAR. A primeira forma era mais formal. Não acredito que se eu falar com alguém mais velho, como um avó/bisavô entenda se seu disser que eu transei com um rapaz. Com certeza haveria uma dúvida da parte desse senhor mais velho: transar? O que ela fez afinal? rs

Comment: Pois é, e ninguém tá falando em trepar. :)

Comment: Parece um caso de 2 substantivos que tem origem em um verbo semelhante, mas não exatamente o mesmo. Uma pessoa que faz uma _transação bancária_, está _transacionando_ com o banco, já se 2 pessoas _transaram_, é por que ocorre uma _transa_ entre eles.